# Losing formatting on reload of data on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am having an issue when I reload the jstree with data from my AJAX call. So on load it works fine, but adding data, and getting a response back the tree loses its structure

Initial html is an empty div, data is updated on button click using ajax

```
<div id="pnlTree">                  

  <div id="jstree" style="text-align: left">

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

```
success: function (data) 
        {
            if( data )
            {
                    var output = '<ul class="appointmentlist">';
                    $.each(data, function(key, val){

                        output += "<li id='"+data[key].data1+"' name='dtpurchase'"+counter+"' value='" + data[key].data2 + "'>" +dtdata + "</li>";
                        //output += '<a id="dtappointment" name="dtpurchase" value="' + data[key].data3 + '"'+ '>'+data[key].purchase_date + '</a>';
                         //output += '</li>';
                         counter++;

                    });
                    output += '</ul>';
                $('#jstree').html(output);
            }

        },
```

[image]

I have tried refreshing, reloading but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Comment: It might help to show what the HTML looked like before the AJAX call and also what the data that gets returned from the AJAX call looks like. Then we can check what the differences are etc.

Comment: its an empty div with ul. I load the data when the page is loaded. I add an appointment and refresh the call from db to pull list of appointments. at this stage it loses its jstree formatting but the data is loading

Comment: I'm thinking it's because jstree has already initialised on document load and it needs to be re-initialised when the data gets returned. I'll see if I can recreate an example for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soooo what you need to do is to `refresh()` the tree after you updated the data.
Now this works only if you append the date to the element with `$("#jstree").jstree(true).settings.core.data = output`. If you use `$('#jstree').html(output)` then it doesn't work

Run the snippets to see it in action:

**Working:**

```js
$('#jstree').jstree()

function update() {
  var output = `<ul><li>New Item</li></ul>`
  $("#jstree").jstree(true).settings.core.data = output
  $('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="jstree">
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button onclick="update()">Update data</button>
```

Okay, so this second one is working with AJAX. It doesn't work in the Stack Overflow sandbox, but it does work on a normal HTML page (see screenshots). It's the exact same concept, you just need to apply it in the right order:

```js
$('#jstree').jstree()

function update() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1", 
    success: function(data){
      var output = `<ul>
        <li>${data.name}</li>
        <li>${data.eye_color}</li>
        <li>${data.height}</li>
      </ul>`
      $("#jstree").jstree(true).settings.core.data = output
      $('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="jstree">
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button onclick="update()">Update data</button>
```

[image: Before AJAX call]

[image: After AJAX call]

Comment: Hi Ludolfyn, thank you, I have an idea now. However when I use $("#jstree").jstree(true).settings.core.data. I am getting an error that settings is not defined. I think this could be because I am using a seperate ajax call from a button click to reload

Comment: Hey @edcoder . Hmmmm, the AJAX call shouldn't be a problem if you're adding the data in the success state. Let me see if I can update the example to include an AJAX call

Comment: do you think it could also be a setting missing from my jstree. The only thing I have set to initialize the tree is $("#jstree").jstree({ }); The data is loaded on ajax success state.

Comment: @edcoder , I added an AJAX example in the answer. I don't think you have to set any settings. I think it's just a matter of calling the functions in the right order, that's all. I did it the exact same way as you without setting any settings. I also just initialized it once and that's it. My initialization looks a little different though. I didn't have an empty object (`{}`) as a parameter. Maybe just try `$("#jstree").jstree()`, without the `{}`

Comment: Hi Ludolfyn, thank you. Followed your example and removed the braces. I appreciate the time you took to clearly explain. More points for that

Comment: Hey @edcoder , no problem at all =) I hope you got it working. Feel free to ask more questions if you're still running into some issues, I don't mind. And thanks for marking the answer and for the upvote!